# OpenJson using a wildcard

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, sql-server-json

I have a SQL query using OPENJSON to import JSON data into a table. My problem is that the data I need is nested. How can I use a wildcard in the JSON path to get what I need?

```
SELECT @Set = 
BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET
(BULK 'Sets.json', DATA_SOURCE = 'MyAzureJson', SINGLE_BLOB) JSON;

INSERT INTO [Sets]
SELECT [name]
FROM OPENJSON(@Set)
WITH(
    [name]      nvarchar(50)    '$.*.name'
)
```

my json file is set up like this..

```
{
    "testOne" : {
        name: "nameOne"
    },
    "testTwo : {
        name: "nameTwo"
    }
}
```

the error I'm getting with everything I try..

JSON path is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '*' is found at position 2.

I've tried . * [] and nothing works

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no support for wildcards in OPENJSON.
Instead you can do a workaround by ignoring the field name in your search. Use `JSON_VALUE` for this.

```
INSERT INTO [Sets]
SELECT
    JSON_VALUE([value], '$.name')
FROM 
    OPENJSON(@Set)
```

Explanation: If you don't define the variables of OPENJSON inside a `WITH` clause and instead do a simple `SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@Set)` query, you will get a result with key, value and type columns (see example output below). Because `key` contains your problematic field name, you can ignore that part and just look into the `value` column of the data.

```
[key]      [value]                [type]
-----      -------                ------
testOne    { name: "nameOne" }    5
testTwo    { name: "nameTwo" }    5
```